# I have 2 implementations of writing to a file. Why is the second version so much faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are the two implementations:

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    console.time("writeMany");
    const fileHandle = await fs.open(path.join(__dirname, '/data/test.txt'), 'w')

    for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        await fileHandle.write(`${i} `);
    }
    console.timeEnd("writeMany");
})();
```

Second version:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    console.time("writeMany");
    fs.open(path.join(__dirname, '/data/test.txt'), 'w', (err, fd) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            fs.writeSync(fd, `${i} `);
        }
    });

    console.timeEnd("writeMany");
})();
```

What is the second version doing that makes it go so much faster? I understand it uses callbacks and so the event loop will process and then execute the callback after the file is opened but I still don't understand why it's so much faster? the callback function goes over a million times just like the first implementation before finishing.

Comment: your first function `await`s a million times, your second does not.

Comment: The first version is creating lots of promises. That's expensive.

Comment: The synchronous API performance might depend on the OS. On MacOS and Linux, I suspect they're call-through methods straight to the platform file API, which internally does its own buffering. When you write 10 bytes, it doesn't immediately flush to the storage device. On Windows it might be a little different but probably basically similar.

Comment: It's only because you're awaiting _and writing_ a million times.  In a real app, you'd probably want to still write asynchronously, but you'd synchronously write the data into a buffer, and then write the buffer to disk asynchronously one chunk at a time.  Optimal buffer size is a complex topic, but is often powers of 2, such as a 4KB or 8KB buffer.

Comment: Node.js does have streaming functions that handle buffered writes.  See examples for `fs.createWriteStream`, etc.

Comment: just a follow up question. Since the first version calls await, does that mean that it frees up the thread between writes so the rest of the program continues? In the second implementation, since it writes sync, that means when the callback function executes, it will block the thread until it writes EVERYTHING right?

Comment: @james not exactly; it will block the thread until the OS API returns, but that does not necessarily mean that the written content has been committed to mass storage (or whatever the output is). (edit: I think)

Comment: If you're going to do synchronous writes, however, it does pay to do your own buffering. The OS will do it too of course, but calling an OS API once every 10 bytes vs once every 32768 bytes means a huge amount of extra overhead; getting into and back out of the OS is expensive.

Comment: @pointy - When you responded to his question about blocking the thread with `await`, it doesn't seem like you're acknowledging that file I/O is done in the separate nodejs threadpool.  The `filehandle.write()` call just needs to be handed off to the thread pool before it can return its promise.

Comment: I would guess that you're just seeing the inefficiency of doing `await somePromise` in a tight loop where each iteration of the loop is doing a very tiny amount of work.  Plus, neither one of these is ever an efficient way to code things since buffered I/O is preferred for lots of writes.  For example, you could use a writeStream much more efficiently.  So, working on trying to explain why two bad ways to write code behave differently seems kind of pointless to me.  Compare two good ways to write the code and then you have a more useful conversation.

Comment: FYI, the second `fs.writeSync()` example, blocks the entire nodejs interpreter during the loop.  The first one does not because each `await` is an opportunity for other code to run.

Comment: @jfriend00 I confess to having very little knowledge about how the *asynchronous* IO stuff in Node works. My comments were about my *suspicions* about how the "synchronous" API works, which (again, guessing) is really only "synchronous" in terms of OS API interactions. In other words, I seriously doubt there's an implicit `flush()` with every synchronous write.

Comment: @jfriend00 also I don't think I was responding about the `await` stuff; I was talking about blocking the thread with the synchronous calls.